# How to build a function to add items to different tables

Tags: variables, tkinter

I currently have several functions that do the same thing. Each function add a value to a different table. I have a subject table, a format table, a studio table, a language table etc.. Each has its own function to add to it. These tables are then used to pull their values into separate dropdowns (GUI).

I would like to create a *single function* that insert values into each of these tables. I use lambda to pass the name of the column. With this I add an 's' to name the table (each table have the same name as the column but plural). Then I use the variable in different place in the function.

If I take the "subject" function. The database *table* is called "subjects," the *column* is called "subject" and the *input box* on the GUI is called "subject_add." Therefore to pull the value from the input box I use "subject_add.get()" Same for all other dropdowns but with different wording.

What I don't know is how to make the "subject_add.get()" work if I use a variable for the word "subject." I have here the function I am currently working on.

```
def add_to_dropdown(column):
    table_name = column + "s"
    element = column + "_add.get()"

    if element:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(conndb.data_source)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(f'INSERT INTO {table_name}({column}) VALUES (?)', (element,))

        messagebox.showinfo("Interest", f"A new {column} has been added to the database")

        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", f"{column} field is empty!")

    column_add.delete(0, tk.END)
```

The table_name variable looks fine. The element variable looks fine, but the "if element:" won't work, as well as the "element" in the SQL INSERT command.

Here is the button with it's lambda command that passes the word "subject" to the function.

```
subject_add_btn = ttk.Button(frame_add_items, text="add ", style='a.TButton', image=arrow, compound=tk.RIGHT, command=lambda: add_to_dropdown("subject"))
subject_add_btn.place(x=480, y=50, height=35, width=90)
```

Hopefully, this makes sense to you. It's not very easy to explain in words. It's easier to show the code.

Comment: Try `element = eval(f'{column}_add.get()')`.

Comment: Or you can save all the entries in a dictionary using column name as the key, then you can use `element = entries[column].get()` instead.

Comment: Thank you acw1668. I nailed it with the eval() function, after talking to another programmer who works with me. However, you just confirmed it with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue is used the eval() functions. Here are the changes I made for it to work well:

```
def add_to_dropdown(column):
    # This function handle all dropdown
    table_name = column + "s"
    element = column + "_add.get()"

    if eval(element):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(conndb.data_source)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(f'INSERT INTO {table_name}({column}) VALUES (?)', (eval(element),))
```

Comment: Better use `element = eval(column+"_add.get()")` so that you don't need to call `eval(element)` twice.

Comment: Good point. I am learning from the best. Thank you.